# Extracting a substring from String with regex in Java (with condition)

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a substring from a string using regex. The tricky (for me) part is that the string may be in one of two formats:

either LLDDDDLDDDDDDD/DDD (eg. AB1000G242424/001) or just between 1 and 7 digits (eg. 242424).

The substring I need to extract would needs to be:
If string is 7 digits or longer, then extract substring consisting of 7 digits.
Else (if string is shorter than 7 digits), then extract substring consisting of 1-6 digits.

Below is one of my tries.

```
    String regex = ("([0-9]{7}|[0-9]{0,6})");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher;

    matcher = pattern.matcher("242424");
    String extractedNr1 = "";

    while (matcher.find()) {
        extractedNr1 += matcher.group();
    }

    matcher = pattern.matcher("AB1000G242424/001");
    String extractedNr2 = "";

    while (matcher.find()) {
        extractedNr2 += matcher.group();
    }

    System.out.println("ExtractedNr1 = " + extractedNr1);
    System.out.println("ExtractedNr2 = " + extractedNr2);
```

Output:

```
ExtractedNr1 = 242424
ExtractedNr2 = 1000242424001
```

I understand the second one is a concat from all the groups, but don't understand why matches are arranged like that. Can I make a regex that will stop immidiately after finding a match (with priority for the first option, that is 7 digits)?
I thought about using some conditional statement, but apparently these are not supported in java.util.regex, and **I cannot use third party library.**
I can do this in java obviously, but the **whole point is in using regex.**

Comment: *Can I make a regex that will stop immidiately after finding a match* - do not put the `find` and `group` logic into a `while` but an `if`.

Comment: I am confused by your question.  _"If string is 7 digits or longer, then extract substring consisting of 7 digits. Else (if string is shorter than 7 digits), then extract substring consisting of 1-6 digits."_  When you say _'string'_, do you mean the entire string, or the sequence of digits within the input string?  You have posted your attempt output, what is your desired output?

Comment: The question may indeed not be clear. The essence is: I need a regex that will extract(find) group(s) consisting of 7 digits if it is possible OR will exctract group(s) of 1-6 digits in case extracting 7 digit groups is not possible (none found). The digits needs to be next to each other in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a secundary concern, the occurrences of digits must be compared by length. As in regex `\d` stand for *digit* and `\D` for *non-digit* you can use `String.splitAsStream` as follows:

```
Optional<String> digits takeDigits(String s) {
    return s.splitAsStream("\\D+")
        filter(w -> !w.isEmpty() && w.length() <= 7)
        max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.replaceAll to remove the non-digit characters:

```
String extracted = new String("AB1000G242424/001").replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
if (extracted.length() > 7)
    extracted = extracted.substring(0, 7);
```

Output:

```
1000242
```

Comment: Yeah, for the problem he has described, that's **exactly right**.  (Unless the problem isn't being explained clearly by the posted question).

Comment: The question may indeed not be clear. The essence is: I need a regex that will extract(find) group(s) consisting of 7 digits if it is possible OR will exctract group(s) of 1-6 digits in case extracting 7 digit groups is not possible (none found). The digits needs to be next to each other in the original string.